# Rust: link failed with exit code 1181

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Error is shown at "cargo run" upon the first example of [Getting started](https://www.rust-lang.org/learn/get-started)

```
C:\Users\HiWin10\hello-rust>cargo run --verbose
   Compiling hello-rust v0.1.0 (C:\Users\HiWin10\hello-rust)
     Running `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name hello_rust src\main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=888d1f7b91fb6e4a -C extra-filename=-888d1f7b91fb6e4a --out-dir C:\Users\HiWin10\hello-rust\target\debug\deps -C incremental=C:\Users\HiWin10\hello-rust\target\debug\incremental -L dependency=C:\Users\HiWin10\hello-rust\target\debug\deps`
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181
  |
  = note: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.1twe2j0sf4nhwv0v.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.1vsfetqgdl2mm9ku.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.2b2k1el9ge2t96a7.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.2wy84pmiszi6o3fj.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.51bmf9dki30948b3.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.q67qbh00yussp5o.rcgu.o" "/OUT:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.exe" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.11f4ns4fn9v6i7z4.rcgu.o" "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-c418a1c7c96bdbae.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-740e55ec30ec9b42.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_demangle-4e3d4b2c73be2130.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libhashbrown-e03c95365300773b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-9b63ec27f8df7123.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libunwind-cc811f306714ba24.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liblibc-dee84a63f4b90027.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc-7d070a58cfb70fe0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-10ec18f1dfe36e70.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-e0e69d50f48d4667.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-45eb0e961cc324b2.rlib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "userenv.lib" "msvcrt.lib"
  = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181:


error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `hello-rust`.

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name hello_rust src\main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=888d1f7b91fb6e4a -C extra-filename=-888d1f7b91fb6e4a --out-dir C:\Users\HiWin10\hello-rust\target\debug\deps -C incremental=C:\Users\HiWin10\hello-rust\target\debug\incremental -L dependency=C:\Users\HiWin10\hello-rust\target\debug\deps` (exit code: 1)

C:\Users\HiWin10\hello-rust>
```

Similar error is shown using intellij-rust in Intellij IDEA

```
C:/Users/HiWin10/.cargo/bin/cargo.exe run --package hello-rust --bin hello-rust
   Compiling hello-rust v0.1.0 (C:\Users\HiWin10\IdeaProjects\hello-rust)
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181
  |
  = note: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.12.25827\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\IdeaProjects\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.1twe2j0sf4nhwv0v.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\IdeaProjects\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.1vsfetqgdl2mm9ku.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\IdeaProjects\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.2b2k1el9ge2t96a7.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\IdeaProjects\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.2wy84pmiszi6o3fj.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\IdeaProjects\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.51bmf9dki30948b3.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\IdeaProjects\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.q67qbh00yussp5o.rcgu.o" "/OUT:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\IdeaProjects\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.exe" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\IdeaProjects\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_rust-888d1f7b91fb6e4a.11f4ns4fn9v6i7z4.rcgu.o" "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\IdeaProjects\\hello-rust\\target\\debug\\deps" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-c418a1c7c96bdbae.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-740e55ec30ec9b42.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_demangle-4e3d4b2c73be2130.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libhashbrown-e03c95365300773b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-9b63ec27f8df7123.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libunwind-cc811f306714ba24.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liblibc-dee84a63f4b90027.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc-7d070a58cfb70fe0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-10ec18f1dfe36e70.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-e0e69d50f48d4667.rlib" "C:\\Users\\HiWin10\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-45eb0e961cc324b2.rlib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "userenv.lib" "msvcrt.lib"
  = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: 


error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `hello-rust`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.

Process finished with exit code 101
```

Since there is no specific names of libraries after LNK1181, I have no idea what is missing. Could you help to suggest how to diagnose ?

PS: A maybe-different error is shown at "cargo run" under Windows Subsystem for Linux

```
testwsl@localdesktop:~/hello-rust$ cargo run
   Compiling hello-rust v0.1.0 (/home/testwsl/hello-rust)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 2
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-m64" "-L" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.1vqvvt1zu5yjmkx2.rcgu.o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.35e6mijtpa61ekwc.rcgu.o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.3guttdxbl4ju2ho3.rcgu.o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.3w3apmysmbwmta20.rcgu.o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.555cq0ss6gtr2lhv.rcgu.o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.pnha9ks6selykbe.rcgu.o" "-o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.2jltqdnkmdrx6xjn.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro" "-Wl,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-9895e8982b0a79e7.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-57306b8ed3378a0e.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libbacktrace_sys-54463ae5adae3649.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-d99667b199a9875a.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-51f4300e102199f5.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-b3ccf1f7737a6a91.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-157c37a3ceb78853.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-505bcee45aafb736.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-c29abd529ba4452b.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-895383a3232f6572.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-5594cb4f559bc761.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-38e90baf978bc428.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-ldl" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-lm" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lutil" "-lutil"
  = note: Non-UTF-8 output: /usr/bin/cc: 1: /usr/bin/cc: \x7fELF\x01\x01\x01\x02\x03\x01\xe4\x90: not found\n/usr/bin/cc: 4: /usr/bin/cc: Syntax error: \"(\" unexpected (expecting \")\")\n

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `hello-rust`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
testwsl@localdesktop:~/hello-rust$ cc
-bash: /usr/bin/cc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
testwsl@localdesktop:~/hello-rust$ cargo run --verbose
   Compiling hello-rust v0.1.0 (/home/testwsl/hello-rust)
     Running `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name hello_rust src/main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=61a6dbe3daa05864 -C extra-filename=-61a6dbe3daa05864 --out-dir /home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps`
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 2
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-m64" "-L" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.1vqvvt1zu5yjmkx2.rcgu.o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.35e6mijtpa61ekwc.rcgu.o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.3guttdxbl4ju2ho3.rcgu.o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.3w3apmysmbwmta20.rcgu.o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.555cq0ss6gtr2lhv.rcgu.o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.pnha9ks6selykbe.rcgu.o" "-o" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps/hello_rust-61a6dbe3daa05864.2jltqdnkmdrx6xjn.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro" "-Wl,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-9895e8982b0a79e7.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-57306b8ed3378a0e.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libbacktrace_sys-54463ae5adae3649.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-d99667b199a9875a.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-51f4300e102199f5.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-b3ccf1f7737a6a91.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-157c37a3ceb78853.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-505bcee45aafb736.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-c29abd529ba4452b.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-895383a3232f6572.rlib" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-5594cb4f559bc761.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/testwsl/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-38e90baf978bc428.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-ldl" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-lm" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lutil" "-lutil"
  = note: Non-UTF-8 output: /usr/bin/cc: 1: /usr/bin/cc: \x7fELF\x01\x01\x01\x02\x03\x01\xe4\x90: not found\n/usr/bin/cc: 4: /usr/bin/cc: Syntax error: \"(\" unexpected (expecting \")\")\n

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `hello-rust`.

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name hello_rust src/main.rs --color always --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=61a6dbe3daa05864 -C extra-filename=-61a6dbe3daa05864 --out-dir /home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/home/testwsl/hello-rust/target/debug/deps` (exit code: 1)
testwsl@localdesktop:~/hello-rust$
```

Comment: Apparently, someone from reddit had the same issue 4 months ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/b26f68/linking_with_linkexe_failed_exit_code_1181_rust/. No proper solution though, except changing toolchain.

Comment: Probably a toolchain issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51659

Comment: I also have the 1181 error when trying to compile a Rust program using GTK on Windows 10(same thing on Debian runs fine).  I am pretty sure my gtk install on Windows is borked.  When I get a chance I will see if I can sort this out.  If I do find a good answer I will post here.

Answer (score 9):

Download and install the [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16). During installation select the **C++ tools**. It will download almost 5GB of data. Then **restart** the machine after installation and compiling the code will work fine.

You can visit this as well [linker-link-exe-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603111/unable-to-compile-rust-hello-world-on-windows-linker-link-exe-not-found/55603112#55603112)