# Is it possible to script python3 selenium to automatically disable CSP for geckodriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

I need to disable CSP for that I can do that manually by opening Firefox() web driver, going to about:config, and disabling:   `security.CSP.enable`.

I am new to selenium, have coded all the stuff I need to just I need to automate disabling of CSP, I don't know much about marionette, capabilities, and other details. I just want to automate the disabling of CSP. Is it possible? Is it possible by doing some capabilities changes or by doing:  `driver.get('about:config'); some code` or by adding another extension? There may be other solutions like downloading geckodriver with no CSP, which I cant find, or maybe even compiling geckodriver with no CSP if its open source.

I cant use chromium for some reason, so I need to work with geckodriver in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the ugliest way, building from source code. Steps:

- Download source of Firefox: [Firefox Source](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/testing/). Then, unzip it.
- cd`/Mozilla-central-83bf4fd3b1fb/testing/geckodriver/src/` and edit prefs.rs with your favourite editor. At end write this:

```rs
// Disable CSP
("security.csp.enable", Pref::new(false)),
```

- Build geckodriver using cargo or mach. I used `cargo build`
- Load it using:

```py
webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./mozilla-central-83bf4fd3b1fb/testing/geckodriver/target/debug/geckodriver')
```

Finding docs and going through the source code and editing was quite painful as I don't know Rust. Here's the docs: [Building Docs](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Building.html)

Answer (score 0):

a small addition, in order to compile the source code on my pc (windows 10), without any other prerequisites prepared, i was required to install rust and c++ build tools ([c++ tools for rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603111/unable-to-compile-rust-hello-world-on-windows-linker-link-exe-not-found))

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30346918)